# Declaring a class type data member in scala (Passing reference of class to another class in scala)

Tags: java, scala

I converted a java code to scala. There are two classes of Java, NodeType.java and Node.java. Similarly they are also named NodeType.scala and Node.scala. I want to call reference of NodeType in Node class. It works perfectly fine in Java. Below is the code snippet for Node.java:

```
public class Node {
public static final Node E = new Node(NodeType.E);
private NodeType nodeType;
```

And the nodeType is used further. Whereas in scala, the code is as follows:

```
object Node{
val E = new Node(NodeType.E)
}
class Node(private var nodeType: NodeType) {
// The method content
}
```

I am getting error at the part`class Node(private var nodeType: NodeType)` 
The error is highlighting on `NodeType` and it says **not found: type NodeType**

Can anyone please help me for this issue ?

Comment: well.. where is the declaration/definition of NodeType: given the above it IS undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you cut and paste from Java into Scala (maybe inside intellij..) . You need to include the definition/declaration of

```
class (/object) NodeType
```

in the code you are working with.